# how to export jstree desired json formatted from etrepat/baum laravel package

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel, jstree

I am using [jstree jQuery plugin](https://www.jstree.com) to display Categories as tree view.

And in the backend, I am using [etrepat/baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) laravel package to create categories nested sets.

**etrepat/baum** package has a method named [toHierarchy()](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#dumping-the-hierarchy-tree) which  returns a nested collection representing the queried tree.

the format of returned is like :

```
    {  
   "7":{  
      "org_level_id":7,
      "parent_id":5,
      "lft":7,
      "rgt":12,
      "depth":0,
      "name":"Computer",
      "created_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
      "updated_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "org_level_id":14,
            "parent_id":7,
            "lft":8,
            "rgt":9,
            "depth":1,
            "name":"hard",
            "created_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
            "updated_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
            "children":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "org_level_id":13,
            "parent_id":7,
            "lft":10,
            "rgt":11,
            "depth":1,
            "name":" RAM",
            "created_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
            "updated_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
            "children":[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "9":{  
      "org_level_id":9,
      "parent_id":2,
      "lft":20,
      "rgt":23,
      "depth":0,
      "name":"search engines",
      "created_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
      "updated_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "org_level_id":18,
            "parent_id":9,
            "lft":21,
            "rgt":22,
            "depth":1,
            "name":"Google",
            "created_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
            "updated_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
            "children":[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "17":{  
      "org_level_id":17,
      "parent_id":10,
      "lft":25,
      "rgt":26,
      "depth":0,
      "name":"Download",
      "created_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
      "updated_at":"2015-11-02 00:45:01",
      "children":[  

      ]
   }
}
```

While on other hand , **JStree plugin** is desired a json format like to create treeview from it :

```
[
   'Simple root node',
   {
     'text' : 'Root node 2',
     'state' : {
       'opened' : true,
       'selected' : true
     },
     'children' : [
       { 'text' : 'Child 1' },
       'Child 2'
     ]
  }
]
```

How can i convert return format of **etrepat/baum** to Appropriate format that **jstree** is desired ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do this on the client or on the server side. Here is a simple function that does it on the server side:

```
// $tree is the result of the toHierarchy assuming it is a JSON string
// if it is not - skip this json_decode step
$tree = json_decode($tree, true);

function parse($data) {
  $temp = [];
  foreach ($data as $id => $v) {
    unset($v['parent_id']);
    $v['id'] = $id;
    $v['text'] = $v['name'];
    if (count($v['children'])) {
      $v['children'] = parse($v['children']);
    }
    $temp[] = $v;
  }
  return $temp;
}

$tree = json_encode(parse($tree));
// now tree contains data that jstree will happily work with
```

The resulting JSON object will work perfectly with jstree. You can of course strip the unneeded attributes using `unset` in order to minimize the amount of data.

Best regards,
Ivan